# Can a JavaScript Object be Converted into an Inline CSS String?

Tags: javascript, css

Given this JavaScript object, which only contains CSS styles.

```
var css = {
    background: '#ccc',
    color: '#333', 
    fontSize: '30px'
};
```

How can I convert it into an inline CSS string? The string should look like this.

```
background: #ccc; color: #333; font-size: 30px
```

My first thought was trying to convert the object into a string.

```
css.toString()
```

But this just gave me `[object Object]`.

The next thing I thought about was parsing it with `RegExp`, but I quickly realised that this would take forever as this should work for all CSS rules, not just the ones listed here.

I have tried to look for libraries and [**Googling**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+css+to+inline+css) doesn't seem to yield anything of use.

I couldn't find any [**packages**](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=css+inline) that did this on NPM. All the packages I see are to do with inlining CSS onto DOM nodes and not producing a string.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Give it a shot, then we can help you if you can't get it

Comment: @JuanMendes Already have, hence the question.

Comment: @Enijar — Show us your attempt, then we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Are you asking "Can I take a javascript object of a certain format and apply the css styles in that format to an element such that it takes the styles listed as inline CSS"? It's not particularly clear what you mean by "inline CSS string" and where you would expect it to go.

Comment: @IStanley Read the question again, it's quite clear.

Comment: @Enijar any integer is not converted to px in my chrome browser `var p = document.createElement("p"); p.style.fontSize = 30; console.log(p.style.fontSize)`

Comment: @Endless Now I know, thanks.

Comment: @Enijar Your question is not nearly as clear as you think it is. "JavaScript Css" is a nonsense term. There is no such thing. You're also completely misusing the term "inline CSS" to mean CSS that has its whitespace removed, so it's no wonder your googling didn't help. You have a JavaScript Object. Of course `toString` doesn't magically turn it into CSS, and "parsing it with RegExp" is a complete non sequitur, you can't *parse* an object.

Comment: @meagar Understood, but that's why I asked the question because those are the things that I was thinking and that's why I couldn't get it to work or find anything. Thankfully I was able to clear the question up enough for some people to help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function style2string(obj){
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    // native version of extending a object
    Object.assign(p.style, obj);

    return p.getAttribute("style");
}

var style = {
    background: '#ccc',
    color: '#333', 
    fontSize: "30px"
};

style2string(style) // "color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 30px; background: rgb(204, 204, 204);"
```

Comment: Brilliant, didn't think adding the style to a virtual DOM node.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery for this purpose:

```
var css = {
  background: '#ccc',
  color: '#333',
  fontSize: 30
};

$('<div/>').css(css).attr('style'); // color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 30px; background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
```

Comment: it's elegant end simple and a good answer but If jQuery was in the tags i would have voted for this answer...

Comment: jQuery is a huge dependency to add for this extremely simple task.